# Inject class inside ampersand operator output in SASS

Tags: css, sass

## Original post

I need to inject a special class inside the & operator output string .. I couldn't make it work as expected :/

I need to change the color value if the section1 element has another class .. So I went this way ..

```
.small {
  // stuff ..
  .section1{
    // stuff ..
    // Multiple nesting levels ..
    #menu{
      color:#fff;
        @at-root selector-replace( &, '.section1', #{'.section1.$active-state'} ){
           color:red;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The following error accurs when I try to compile this snippet:

**Invalid CSS after "selector-replace": expected selector, was "( &, ..."**

This has been driving me crazy for a couple of hours now .. Could someone help me understand what's going wrong here ?

__

## EDIT

The previous code was a simplified version of my actual code and problem. It appears that what should have fixed the previous snippet do not solve my problem but introduce a side effect..

So here is my problem now .. Giving this code ..

And here is the code:

```
$small-mode:'.small-mode';
$menu-active-state:'menu-active';
    #{$small-mode} {
        #main-menu {
            padding:0px;
            
            #menu-button-container{
                height:25px;
                width:30px;
                padding:7px;
                background-color: #fff;
                .menu-trigger {
                    height: 25px;
                }
                
            }
            > ul{
                display: none;
            }
            #fp-nav{
                left:12px;
            }
            
            @at-root #{selector-replace( &, '#main-menu', '.#{$menu-active-state} #main-menu') } {
            /*! ~~ */
                height:1%;
            }
        }
}
```

The "`@at-root`" outputs

`.small-mode .menu-active #main-menu,.menu-active .small-mode #main-menu`

instead of

`.small-mode .menu-active #main-menu`

I'm almost there but a comma followed by an unexpected selector is printed

Thank you.

Comment: Check the entire answer in the linked question for all of your available options.  I don't have an answer as to why Sass is generating 2 selectors, but it is related to replacing a simple selector with a compound selector.

Comment: Thank you for your time ; I will post another question for that.